# How to find all text between the first pair of bracket when there is also brackets in the text?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings that look like:

```
Item Q55127831 (Acute nitrobenzene poisoning with transient (optional) amino-aciduria.) > setting P921 to Q114953 (poisoning)
```

I want to extract:

```
Acute nitrobenzene poisoning with transient (optional) amino-aciduria.
```

Where there could be internal parenthesis (optional) or not.

I use Python 3

I tried with Regex1 and Regex2 above:

```
import re
regExp1 = "\(([^)]+)\)"
regExp2 = "\$\{((?:\{[^\{\}]*\}|[^\{\}]*)*)\}"
str = "Item Q55127831 (Acute nitrobenzene poisoning with transient (optional) amino-aciduria.) > setting P921 to Q114953 (poisoning)"
x = re.search(regExp2, str)[1,-1]
print(x)
```

regExp1 give:

```
Acute nitrobenzene poisoning with transient (optional
```

regExp2 give:

```
none
```

Could you help if you have more suitable solution?

Thanks

Comment: For a regex solution: https://regex101.com/r/GMV4iD/1

Comment: Thanks. It seems ok in regex101 but when I export a Python code or try it in my code it raise "error: invalid group reference 1 at position 28" or "none" if I remove the raw string r"xxx".

Comment: Gosh, I hope 'regex101' is using the Python re module. Maybe you should contact them ~